# Part of name of a variable to be a variable

Tags: linux, bash

Let's suppose I have following two variables:

```
arg1=5
count5="test"
```

Now, I want to able to do something like:

```
echo ${'count' . $arg1} #which should give me "test" but its returning bad-substitution error
```

i.e. can part of a variable can be set as variable in bash?

Comment: I didn't see the rest of the code, but there surely is a better way that doesn't involve that solution. Arrays maybe?

Comment: The classic answer (portable to shells derived from the Bourne shell) would be `eval`, but the 'indirect variable reference' is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, got it working via indirect variable reference introduced in Bash v2 as:

```
my_var="count$arg1"
echo ${!my_var}
```

Comment: While this works, it may be better to use an array: `arr[5]="test"`. In bash, arrays are sparse, so you can assign element 5 without assigning 0-4.