# Variable Naming within Excel

Tags: xml, excel, vba

Okay, so here's a question that I pretty much want to ask: [Part of name of a variable to be a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12132307/part-of-name-of-a-variable-to-be-a-variable)

But the character $ is not allowed in Excel VBA. Is there another character/function that allows me to pretty begin compiling the line within the brackets so to speak before the rest of the line?

Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
    ActiveWorkbook.XMLImport URL:= _
 "http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?typeid=" & ${'TypeIDs' . $z} & "&usesystem=30000142", _
  ImportMap:=ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps("EVEMinerals"), _
  Overwrite:=True, Destination:=Range("ISKValues!$H$" & z * 100)
```

It is part of a loop function with z acting as the looping variable. I have a bunch of variables named TypeIDs1, 2, 3 etc etc and I want to retrieve each of them in a set of XML Imports without having to do an if it exists for each one?

I would also like to know if I can set the destination to be below another XML map by automatic (I couldn't find a function to work on the length of non-blank cells that actually worked)?

Answer (score 0):

In VBA, the **name** of a variable does not change, its **contents** can certainly change

```
Destination:=Range("ISKValues!$H$" & z * 100)
```

assumes that **z** is numerical........so:

```
Range("ISKValues!$H$" & CStr(z * 100))
```

would be acceptable syntax

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. Either way would work fine for the range as z will always be a numerical value. My issue is not with that, but with the paragraph above that.

Comment: If the issue is with **URL:=** stringvariable  ...........  the stringvariable can be constructed by concatenating sub-string and sub-string **arrays**